# Provide a dynamically a mocked class causes " Function calls are not supported in decorators but..." error in prod mode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Angular 8 (ionic) project. Where I want to mock some native providers. I have created this class

```
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version/ngx';
import { Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { AppVersionMock } from './mocks/app-version.mock';

export class NativePluginsWithMocks {
  public static getProviders(): Provider[] {
    let providers;
    const isCordovaEnvirionment = (window as any)['cordova'];

    if (isCordovaEnvirionment) {
      // Use device providers
      providers = [AppVersion];
    } else {
      // Use browser providers
      providers = [{ provide: AppVersion, useClass: AppVersionMock }];
    }

    return providers;
  }
}
```

And I provide it on my module

```
import { NativePluginsWithMocks } from './native-plugins-with-mocks/native-plugins-with-mocks';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [
    ...NativePluginsWithMocks.getProviders(),
    SplashScreen,
    StatusBar,
    ScreenOrientation,
    NativeToast,
    AdMobFree,
    SecureStorage,
    Device,
    Market,
    File,
    AndroidPermissions,
    InAppPurchase2,
    Network,
    NativeStorage,
    {
      provide: StorageService,
      useFactory: storageServiceFactory,
      deps: [Storage, NativeStorage, LoggerService, Platform]
    }
  ]
})
export class IonicNativePluginsModule {}
```

It works while on `dev` mode but in `prod` mode the compiler sends an error:

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'IonicNativePluginsModule'
>   [ng]   Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'NativePluginsWithMocks' was called.

Is there a way to make this work on production mode? I think I could wrap it in a factory but that would mean I have to create a lot of boiler plate code for each mock. I am seeing something wrong?

Comment: Dynamic code is not allowed in AOT compilation. Why are you importing your mocks in the module though? Isn't it supposed to be for tests? What are you using mocks for?

Comment: @BlindDespair It is needed for local development in Browser because Native Plugins need a cordova Environment.